# Codeigniter setting upload path to tmp folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm uploading my files to Amazon S3 and don't need to store them locally. Instead of using `unlink()` or cron jobs I want to add the files to the `tmp` folder and send them to Amazon S3 from there. I tried specifying the path in config options:

```
$tmp = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
$config['upload_path'] = $tmp;
```

and I get an upload error:

`The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.`

I made my tmp folder writable and still get the error. Does anyone know how to upload just to tmp folder using the CI upload library? I'm afraid that I might have to modify the core upload library removing all upload path functions.

Comment: Why you can't use $_FILES['fieldname'][tmp_name] directly ?

Comment: that gets the filename. I need to specify the tmp folder. using `/tmp/` in the filepath seems to work

Comment: You can' write tmp folder of server. you will get tmp file path in $_FILES['fieldname'][tmp_name] so when you upload any file it gets store into tmp folder that path you will get using $_FILES['fieldname'][tmp_name] and you can use this path to upload your file to Amzaon S3

Comment: `/tmp/` in path appears to work. I can get the filename using `$this->upload->file_name` and gives me the tmp_name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `ini_get()` is a representation of php.ini.

If you open up `php.ini` you'll find that `upload_tmp_dir` is set to `null`

If you `echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');` you'll probably notice that it won't - that's because it's `null`. Which means you're feeding an empty string into `$config['upload_path']` and CodeIgniter will choose your document root by default.

Use `sys_get_temp_dir()` or simply `'/tmp'`, instead.

Comment: I know this is old...but it helped point me in the right direction.  So thanks!