# Getting error as The temporary folder is missing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using nginx and codeigniter file upload working in one server but it was not working in other server getting

> `{"error":true,"message":"<p>The temporary folder is missing.<\/p>"}`

what may be the issue , here is the code

```
$path = '/assets/document/'
$config['upload_path']   = $path;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf';
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
    $json = array(
        'error' => true,
        'message' => $this->upload->display_errors()
    );
    echo json_encode($json);
} else {
    $upload_details = $this->upload->data();
    echo $upload_details['file_name'];
}
```

getting output as `{"error":true,"message":"<p>The temporary folder is missing.<\/p>"}`

anything needs to added in nginx?

Comment: Check the temp dir: $tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir()  and also, check folder permissions. Are you allowed to write? Also check this comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875776/codeigniter-setting-upload-path-to-tmp-folder)

Comment: The error indicates that the PHP configuration on your server does not have a valid `upload_tmp_dir` setting. This setting specifies the temporary directory where PHP stores the uploaded files before moving them to the final destination. Check the `php.ini` file and look for the `upload_tmp_dir` setting.